Как реализовать масштабирование дочерних окон внутри MDI-интерфейса без изменения их фактического размера (свойств Width и Height)?
Ранее уже писал код для подобной задачи в приложении на WinForms. В тот раз использовал для этого матрицу, а масштабировать нужно было рисунок. Думал что и окна можно масштабировать по такому же принципу, но не вышло - изображение вокруг окон и в самих окнах масштабируется, а вот сами окна нет.
Пробовал отказаться от MDI-интерфейса и добавить дочерние окна на панель (Panel) в качестве контролов, но это также не помогло.
Остается вариант с изменением размера окон и их содержимого, но это уж больно колхозно, и мне кажется что должен быть более правильный вариант, позволяющий масштабировать только визуальную часть. Требуется мне это для того чтобы можно было масштабировать окна с помощью колеса мышки (это важная составляющая интерфейса).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли корректное решение для реализации функциональности масштабирования?

В стандартном MDI интерфейсе нет встроенного функционала для визуального масштабирования окон без изменения из размеров. Поэтому лучше отказаться от MDI и реализовать собственный контейнер, на котором дочерние окна являются контролами. Тогда можно будет переопределить OnPaint у контейнера, и масштабировать его содержимое с помощью Graphics.Tansform.

@Uranus спасибо за ответ! Получилось с помощью метода Scale у контейнера (использовал Panel). Но метод меняет свойства Width и Height контролов, плюс рамка окна не масштабируется - только меняется его размер. Хотелось бы этого избежать и масштабировать только изображение, не меняя свойства окна...

Через Transform не получается, изменения масштаба не проиходит.
